# DateTime.Now.AddSeconds equivalent in IronPython

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, ironpython

is there an equivalent of `DateTime.Now.AddSeconds()` in `IronPython` and if there is none, how to achieve it in `IronPython`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DateTime` is part of the .Net framework, from the `System` namespace.  Anything in the framework is pretty much the same regardless of what language you use.

The following is valid in IronPython:

```
import System
dt = System.DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(30)
```

The following is a screenshot from the console window in [the interactive tutorial](http://ironpython.net/ironpython/try/).

[image: Iron Python Demo 1]

The above assumes you really want to use the .Net `System.DateTime` object.  But if you are doing a lot in python, you may want to use the Python `datetime` class instead.  In Python, the *timedelta* class works very similar to the `TimeSpan` class in .Net:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
dt = datetime.now() + timedelta(seconds = 30)
```

This will work in  *any* python interpreter, including IronPython.  Below is another screenshot from the consol window in the IronPython interactive tutorial:

[image: Iron Python Demo 2]